# Out of 36 random drawings what are the odds of numbers 1-12 each coming up 3 times?

Tags: probability

If you had 12 possible outcomes what are the odds that each outcome would come up exactly 3 times out of 36 drawings?

So I'm going to make a random drawing 36 times and the outcome can be numbers 1-12. What are the odds, that each number would come out exactly 3 times?

(note each number is NOT removed after being drawn, it is put back in so there are always 12 possible outcomes (#'s 1-12)

I would assume that it is 12 (# of outcomes) x 36 (number of drawings) = 432

Then divide this by 3 (times each number coming up) 432 / 3 = 144

So 1 in 144 times?

Although, I feel this is way off. Perhaps it is 12 to the 36th power?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! The best way to get useful answers to your questions on this site is to give us some information about your background in the subject, and what you have tried in attempting to solve the problem.

Comment: It is my own view, but *please stop down-voting newbie posts without giving him any opportunity to acclimatize here*. Some users here possess such greatly culpable tendency of down-voting newbie posts, they never remove their down-vote even after editing the question correctly and making it clear.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Unfortunately, as a math newb I'm not exactly sure what that means

Comment: Where is your confusion?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey I understand that we are looking at fractals. (and so 36! is 36 x 35 x 34 x 33..... etc. yes?)

However, I'm not sure how to use this to find the odds of this mock scenario (it's relating to roulette)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the opportunity to draw $36$ times, and in each draw $12$ outcomes can occur. So, there are $\color{blue}{12^{36}}$ possibilities.

Now, when you under the criteria that each of the $12$ outcomes will occur *exactly thrice* out of the $36$ drawing, then you may consider this metaphorically, that you have *$12$ types of different balls* and in each type, you have *$3$ identical balls*.

So, number of permutations of these balls is $$\color{blue}{\frac {36!}{\underbrace{3!\times 3!\dots \times3!}_{12\text{times}}}=\frac {36!}{(3!)^{12}}}.$$

So the required probability is $$\bbox[border:3px solid blue]{\color{red}{\frac{36!/(3!)^{12}}{12^{36}}}}$$

Comment: Thanks so much Subhadeep Dey! I understand now! How would one evaluate this and convert it to a percentage though? The numbers get too large for all my calculators.

Comment: @Susan, this is the answer, you need not proceed anymore. That will be unnecessary approach.

Comment: I understand. And this is best answer so will tick for you.

If I'm trying to know the percentage of the time this event will happen (each # 1-12 coming up 3 times in 36) say out of 1 million events (The 36 times being 1 event.)... how would I do that?

Comment: As I said earlier, finding percentage is unnecessary. And if you want to know the percentage, then you have to reduce the fraction, and multiply that with $100$%. I think, if you start counting this percentage today, then the fourth generations after you will surely be able to complete this! So, you better use the softwares like *Derive, Mathematica or Maple.*

Comment: Thank you for all your help!